# Drupal and Symfony fusion

Tags: php, drupal, symfony1

This probably comes across as a very naive question, and I am absolutely assuming I'll get panned for this, but nevertheless:

I have an existing Drupal website that is not meeting it's needs. The dilemma is straightforward, half the website needs requires Drupal and the other half is probably better done using a framework such as Symfony. I wasn't smart enough to judge this before, else I would have used Symfony + Sympal to achieve my needs.

But now I have an existing website in Drupal with substantial content added to it and a growing need to create another module that very specifically achieves the goals of the application layer on the website. There isn't time for me to sit down and learn the nuances of Drupal's module building and all that jazz when I can comfortably do it within Symfony.

My challenge here is to understand if there is a possibility to introduce Symfony into my existing website and somehow link the two?

Thanks for your opinions, feel free to ask me to elaborate !

Comment: Is running the symfony part on a different virtual host an option? For example running Drupal from www.example.com and Symfony from myapp.example.com. This would be the cleanest separation of the two, without possible clashing.

Comment: You don't have the time to learn Drupal internal and expect it would be easier ton integrate Symfony into it?

Comment: Gerry can you elaborate a little more?  At it's simplest, I can have a Drupal Menu path pointing to an external link which would be this path. But then again, this would require a communication channel between the two, since certain users can access the full functionality created in Symfony whereas the regular users only access a subset of the functionality. Essentially, the path to the Symfony app is through Drupal, and would require the login credentials in order to render appropriately. Can get murky and complicated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been putting some time into the [Symfony Drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/symfony), which allows you to call the Symfony framework from your own modules. As long as your module depends on "symfony", you will be able to access the Symfony namespace classes.

Comment: that seems like a spectacular effort to integrate the two, I'll check it out and gauge if it fits my needs, thanks for answering :p